# Can't deploy to GKE by a specific linux user

Tags: linux, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, kubectl

We have a Jenkins virtual machine on GCE which deals with deployments, including the ones we do to GKE. We've tried to deploy a project which we have not touched for some time. The deployment failed when calling

`kubectl set image deployment my-deployment my-deployment=gcr.io/my-project/my-project:version-tag`

getting this error:

`Error from server (Forbidden): deployments.extensions "my-deployment" is forbidden: User "client" cannot get resource "deployments" in API group "extensions" in the namespace "default"`

The weird thing is, if I log in to the machine, use my Linux user + my gcloud user, I can deploy fine. But when switching to the jenkins user using `su - jenkins` and then authorizing gcloud with my user I get this same error that our deploy account gets.

Please advise how to fix.

Comment: You will most probably copy ~/.kube/config from the working users home directory to the user where it doesn't work.

Comment: @RamanSailopal copy the config files from the user that it works for to the user that it doesnt?

Comment: Copy from /home/Linux user/.kube/config to /home/jenkins/.kube/config

Comment: that didnt work :(

Answer (score 1):

It seems related to cluster RBAC configurations. Did you enable the [RBAC fo Google Groups](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control#google-groups-for-gke)? In this case you should follow the instructions in the documentation above or disable it.

Otherwise, ss Raman Sailopal stated, you can try this:

- with your regular user run `kubectl config get-contexts` to retrieve your current context
- copy from `/home/Linux user/.kube/config` to `/home/jenkins/.kube/config`
- change user to jenkins and be sure you're using the same context by running `kubectl config get-contexts` and `kubectl config set-context ...`
- try your rights with:

```sh
  # Check to see if I can create deployments in any namespace
  kubectl auth can-i create deployments

  # Check to see if I can list deployments in my current namespace
  kubectl auth can-i list deployments.extensions
```